# Python How to pass *argv to sub function

Tags: python-2.7, arguments

I want to pass *argv arguments to a sub function:

```
1   def a(*argv):
2      print "a" + str(argv)
3   
4   def b(*argv):
5       print "b" + str(argv)
6       a(argv)
7   
8   b(1, 2, 3)
```

Here is the output I get :

> b(1, 2, 3)
>
> a((1, 2, 3),)

At line 6, argv is passed as a whole tupple counting as one parameter. This is not the result I want.

I would like to have :

> b(1, 2, 3)
>
> a(1, 2, 3)

How can I get the desired results ? Something like :

```
6    a(argv[0], argv[1],...argv[n])
```

but n is unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. Adding * in line 6 does the tricks.

```
1   def a(*argv):
2      print "a" + str(argv)
3   
4   def b(*argv):
5       print "b" + str(argv)
6       a(*argv)
7   
8   b(1, 2, 3)
```